# Swift, MapKit, CLLocation how to avoid toll roads

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have this code to update and save the location of users on a array now how can I identify if the user is on a toll/highway road?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    userLocationForDirections = locations[0] as CLLocation

    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    var userLatitude = (userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    var userLongitude = (userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    userMoves = [userLatitude, userLongitude]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try looking at `MKDirectionsResponse` object. It contains an array of `MKRoute` objects and each `MKRoute` has an `advisoryNotices` (String) that contains information about the route. No guarantee that it will always have toll info but it may....